# Нельзя менять(делать update) значение ячейки ни на что, кроме определенного значения в MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

есть некая таблица People:

Id    |    Name     | Age

1     |    Миша     | 22

2     |    Коля     | 30

запускаю команду update (Update People Set Age = 15, where Name = 'Коля')

ВОТ ЗАДАЧКА:
Таблица People должна обновится, если значение поля Age больше 18 (Age >= 18).
Как это реализовать ?

Comment: Ну и добавьте к своему UPDATE дополнительное условие AND  Age >= 18

Comment: вы хотите установить минимальный возраст который можно ввести, или что?

Comment: именно так, @teran . Если значение поля Age будет меньше 18 при операции update, то таблица не должна обновляться.

Comment: исходное значение, или вставляемое? еще какие то поля обновляются,кроме возраста?

Comment: @teran, Age нельзя менять на значение меньше 18, то есть команда "Update People Set Age = 15, where Name = 'Коля' "не должна сработать . Остальные поля могут изменяться если не указывать Age или же когда Age будет >= 18.

Answer (score 0):

можете реализовать ограничение для столбца `age`

```
CREATE TABLE #xxx (
   name VARCHAR(10),
   age INT,
   CHECK (age >= 18)
)

INSERT INTO #xxx (name , age) VALUES ('Василий', 20);
UPDATE #xxx set age = 15 WHERE name = 'Василий';

SELECT * FROM #xxx;
DROP TABLE #xxx;
```

в результате выполнения этого кода вы получите исключение.

либо смотрите в сторону триггеров `INSTEAD OF UPDATE`, проверите если столбец `age` не обновлялся, или обновлялся, но значение валидное, то обновите.

Comment: INSERT INTO #xxx (name , age) VALUES ('Василий', 12);  Эта команда тоже должна сработать

Comment: @Aliden и? вставлено не будет. надо чтобы вставлялось, но не обновлялось что ли?

Comment: @Aliden вы не кажется что это надо также описывать в вопросе?

Comment: в точку попали! Надо чтобы вставлялось, но не обновлялось

Comment: приношу извинения